# Collecting extra information using Dot Net's standard authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using the inbuilt dot net authentication to register users in a simple web site and trying to add some extra information to be collected on registration.

It currently asks for Usernname, email, password, confirm password. I'd like to add some extra bits, something like "favourite colour" - just a simple string.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Maybe a simple tutorial I could follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna look into ASP.NET profiles. There is a good intro [here](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx) - and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a look at that now.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the CreateUserWizard control, so I had some difficulty implementing the info I learned from Alistad's answer.

This article got me the rest of the way there - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx